# Get the html tag from an element without the inner text content

Tags: javascript, html, outerhtml

Using **Javascript** I'm looking to take a DOM element and take just it's **tag**, **class**, **id**, etc (the stuff in brackets), but ignore the actual *text content* within. Kind of like the opposite of `innerHTML`/`textContent`.

So I'm hoping to get a div like this:

`<p id="foo">Ipsum Lorem</p>`

into a string this:

`<p id="foo"> </p>`

Comment: take the nodename and concat the attributes as a string

Comment: What do you mean by "take" them? Do you actually need the result in HTML tag format?

Comment: By take I mean get a string of the html inside the brackets

Comment: If all you need is what's inside the brackets, then it's not really a tag. Using Daniel's answer, you can get the attribute keys and values individually. So the best solution depends what you're ultimately going to be doing with the data. And just so you know, you never get the original HTML. It needs to be re-created from the DOM nodes, so it may not be exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) or if you don't want to use that:

Get the nodename and reduce the elements attributes into a string.

```
'use strict';

const elem = document.getElementById('foobar');
const nodeName = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase();
const attrs = [...el.attributes].map((a) => {
  if (a.value === '')
    return a.name;
  else if (a.value.indexOf('"') > -1)
    return `${a.name}='${a.value}'`;
  else
    return `${a.name}="${a.value}"`;
}).join(' ');
const str = `<${nodeName} ${attrs}></${nodeName}>`;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k22tyqbr/3/

Comment: You just re-implemented `elem.cloneNode().outerHTML`. Beware of attribute values that contain a double-quote character.

Comment: wasn't aware of `.cloneNode`...but an attribute can contain a double quote? never knew that.

Comment: Yes, if it uses single quotes as value delimiters `<div data-say='bob says "hello"'></div>` Your code will still work, but the attribute value in the result will be malformed.

Comment: Is this better than just using **cloneNode()**?

Comment: @JonSG probably not, didnt know about that method

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `innerHTML` inside the `outerHTML` with either nothing, or as I did here, ellipses, "...":

```
var txt = elem.outerHTML.replace(elem.innerHTML, '...');
```

After selecting the element (`getElementById("foo")`),

`<p id="foo">Ipsum Lorem</p>`

this will return a `string` into `var txt`

`<p id="foo">...</p>`

Comment: @Jamesonthedog: There's nothing wrong with that, but the answer as a general solution is painful.

Comment: Too much unnecessary serializing of the DOM elements an unnecessary search. Granted, there are only two nodes there, but in the general case that would be pretty massive overkill. You can clone the node without the content by doing `elem.cloneNode()`. Then all you need is `.outerHTML`. I don't know if you actually wanted new content or not.

Comment: ...also, I'm pretty sure this could give unexpected results in some cases.